# What do you think about this introduction to answering Yes/No questions?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, yes-no-questions

I have found a lot of information about asking questions but very little about answering them.

I want to create a rule to help learners answer affirmative/negative questions in Chinese. Presently I ask them to identify the following in a sentence: copulas, modals, main verbs or solitary adjectives and then use them in one or two-word answers. My question is how would you answer the following questions in the simplest way:

1. 李先生在吗？
2. 他是你的朋友吗？
3. 李先生很累吗？
4. 你要这张卡片吗？
5. 李先生有朋友吗？

Comment: Most frequently and informally I would use 嗯 to 4th tone to make 'yes' answers, 嗯 to the reverse 2nd tone (243) to make 'no' answers and 嗯 to 1st tone to give an uncertain answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a suggestion, so it should be moved to Chinese Language Meta

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an open question about teaching Chinese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First answer is yes, and next answer is no:

1. 李先生在吗？
   在/不在
2. 他是你的朋友吗？
   是/不是
3. 李先生很累吗？
   累(This is shortest, but in real life people wouldn't answer like that)/不累(This is native.)
4. 你要这张卡片吗？
   要/不要
5. 李先生有朋友吗？
   有/没有

And using the 嗯 to make no answer is not the right way, people don't speak like that.

Comment: @user3306356 I don't have the privilege to comment you answer, so I'll write it down here. Use 嗯 to make the 'yes' answer is fine, and to make the other 2 answers is controversial. Use 2nd tone to hint a doubt, that would probably acceptable. But I don't see anyone using 嗯 to negate in real life.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know how much I can discover...and I'm not writing that strict rules.

- One can combine Ma with a negative sentence, and its answer is
  always reverse to the western logic.

e.g.

> -你们还没吃饭吗？
>
> -不，吃了。/对，没吃。

- Thus there are direct answers as simplified compound answers based on
  main verb.

是的／对／对的－不是／不对、 是的－（还）没有 、 有的－没有。

- Note that **你吃了吗?** is not really a question asking if you have had meal, but somehow a kind of invitation. The right way to answer is

> -你吃了吗?
>
> -吃得可好了。

if you have had your meal and don't want to be invited.

Any other answer leads to the consequence of being invited.

Answer (score 1):

Answering everything with:

嗯

is perfectly acceptable and can avoid having to have any sort of conversation!